# Custom Hashset in Java

Tags: java, reinventing-the-wheel, hash-map, set

I have written this custom hashset and though it isn't completed yet, I would like to know if there is anything I am overlooking in terms of clean code conventions. My aim was also to apply generics to it. So, would also want any input regarding that.

```
  public class CustomHashset<T> {

    private static final int SIZE = 100;
    private Entry<T>[] buckets;
    private int size;

    public CustomHashset() {
      this.buckets = new Entry[SIZE];
      this.size= 0;

    }

    private int hash(T element) {
        return element.hashCode() % buckets.length;
    }

    public Boolean add(T element) {
        int index = hash(element);

        Entry<T> current = buckets[index];
        while (current!=null) {
            if (current.key.equals(element)) return false;
            current = current.next;
        }
        Entry<T> entry = new Entry<T>();
        entry.setKey(element);
        entry.setNext(buckets[index]); 
        buckets[index] = entry;
        size++;

        return true;
    }

    public int size() {
        return size;
    }

    private static class Entry<T> {
        private T key;
        private Entry next;

        public  T getKey() {
            return key;
        }

        public void setKey(T element) {
            this.key = element;
        }

        public Entry getNext () {
            return next;
        }

        public void setNext(Entry next) {
            this.next = next;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Request for Clarification: do you want your CustomHashSet to be a HashSet? i.e., do you want this to be valid: `HashSet<T> hashSet = new CustomHashSet<>();`

Comment: @Wood Glass, no.

Comment: What are your design goals? Is there a reason that `java.util.HashSet` will not suffice? Do you want to integrate nicely with the Java Collections Framework, or avoid it entirely? It is hard to review this code without more context.

Comment: @BenjaminKuykendall, simply learning how to implement these data structures using generics.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Problems with generics

- `Entry<T>.next` should have type `Entry<T>`.
- `CustomHashset<T>.buckets` has type `Entry<T>[]` but is initialized to an `Entry[]`. Initializing a generic array properly is annoying, but [this StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/529085/how-to-create-a-generic-array-in-java) explores a few solutions. At the end of the day, there's only so much you can do about it; you can at least suppress the compiler warning though.

### Interface of `Entry`

You never use the getters and setters. Remove them.

### Abstract out linked list

As you implement more methods, it should become apparent that you are using the chain of `Entry<T>` objects as a linked list. Thus the interface it presents could be more abstract: in fact, I would create a `LinkedList<T>` class with `add(T t)` and `contains(T t)` methods. Then make `buckets` an array of `LinkedList<T>`. This way, the hash set never has to deal with individual entries.

### Small problems

- Use or omit `this` more consistently. I would omit it unless needed.
- Return `boolean` not `Boolean`.
- Currently, `a null` key causes a `NullPointerException` when you call `hash()`. You should detect `null` inputs to `add` and explicitly throw an `IllegalArgumentException` instead.
- Use default visibility instead of public to expose methods of private inner classes.

Comment: Thanks for your review. Very interesting take.
1. I really didn't have any problem initializing the generic array. Maybe there is something you can point to in the way I have initialized it for a better understanding. I took a look at the link you added and it appears I was doing something close to the checked except I wasn't wrapping it in the way it was explained over there.

2. I did use the setters but not the getters. So, I will remove the getters. Thanks for that.

Continuation ...below

Comment: 3. Could you elaborate further on the 'Abstract out linked list'? I get you want me to make the Entry<T> a LinkedList<T> because, under the hood, I was using node chaining. I don't get making buckets an array of LinkedList<T>. Even though I could do that, would I not be relying on an existing implementation? I could very well have just added a Java HashMap internally and not bother about implementing the hashing and the add contains e.t.c as I would just be calling the hashMap operators under the hood. So, just want to know if this is  Ok to do.

Comment: I would also ditch the setters in favor of a constructor: `Entry<T>(T element, Entry<T> next)`. If you do this, you can even make both fields `final`. If you don't want to use `java.util.LinkedList`, writing your own `CustomLinkedList` that supports `add` and `contains` is really easy; in fact you have most of the code there, it's just a mater of reorganizing it.

Answer (score 2):

***Improving names:***

- Your class has 2 `size` variables, which looks kinda strange. Better to rename this private static one to something like `INITIAL_CAPACITY` (or `DEFAULT_INITIAL_CAPACITY`, if you have plans adding constructor with `initialCapacity` parameter), because size = how many elements are stored, but this variable denotes initial array length.
- method `hash` in reality returns bucket index for given element, thus, should be renamed. For example, to `indexFor` or `bucketIndex`.

***Other:***

- in `Entry` - `next` is not parameterized (as well as its getter and setter).